# Webhook process run on another goroutine

Tags: http, go, server, goroutine

I want to run some slow routine in another goroutine, is it safe to do it like this:

```
func someHandler(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
   go someReallySlowFunction() // sending mail or something slow
   fmt.Fprintf(w,"Mail will be delivered shortly..")
}

func otherHandler(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
   foo := int64(0)
   bar := func() {
      // do slow things with foo
   }
   go bar()
   fmt.Fprintf(w,"Mail will be delivered shortly..")
}
```

Is there any gotchas by doing this?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Serving each http request runs in its own goroutine ([more details on this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37529511/process-management-for-the-go-webserver)). You are allowed to start new goroutines from your handler, and they will run concurrently, independently from the goroutine executing the handler.

Some things to look out for:

- The new goroutine runs independently from the handler goroutine. This means it may complete before or after the handler goroutine, you cannot (should not) assume anything regarding to this without explicit synchronization.
- The [`http.ResponseWriter`](https://golang.org/pkg/net/http/#ResponseWriter) and [`http.Request`](https://golang.org/pkg/net/http/#Request) arguments of the handler are only valid and safe to use until the handler returns! These values (or "parts" of them) may be reused - this is an implementation detail of which you should also not assume anything. Once the handler returns, you should not touch (not even read) these values.
- Once the handler returns, the response is committed (or may be committed at any moment). Which means your new goroutine should not attempt to send back any data using the `http.ResponseWriter` after this. This is true to the extent that even if you don't touch the `http.ResponseWriter` in your handler, not panicing from the handler is taken as a successful handling of the request and thus HTTP 200 status is sent back ([see an example of this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27972715/multiple-response-writeheader-calls-in-really-simple-example)).

You are allowed to pass the `http.Request` and `http.ResponseWriter` values to other functions and to new goroutines, but care must be taken: you should use explicit synchronization (e.g. locks, channels) if you intend to read / modify these values from multiple goroutines (or you want to send back data from multiple goroutines).

Note that seemingly if both your handler goroutine and your new goroutine just reads / inspects the `http.Request`, that still may be problematic. Yes, multiple goroutines can read the same variable without synchronization (if nobody modifies it). But calling certain methods of `http.Request` also modify the `http.Request`, and without synchronization there is no guarantee what other goroutines would see from this change. For example [`Request.FormValue()`](https://golang.org/pkg/net/http/#Request.FormValue) returns a form value associated with the given key. But this method calls [`ParseMultiPartForm()`](https://golang.org/pkg/net/http/#Request.ParseMultipartForm) and [`ParseForm()`](https://golang.org/pkg/net/http/#Request.ParseForm) if necessary which modify the `http.Request` (e.g. they set the `Request.PostForm` and `Request.Form` struct fields).

So unless you synchronize your goroutines, you should not pass `Request` and `ResponseWriter` to the new goroutine, but acquire data needed from the `Request` in the handler goroutine, and pass only e.g. a `struct` holding the needed data.

Your second example:

```
foo := int64(0)
bar := func() {
   // do slow things with foo
}
go bar()
```

This is perfectly fine. This is a [closure](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Function_literals), and local variables referred by it will survive as long as they are accessible.

Note that alternatively you could pass the value of the local variable to the anonymous function call as an argument like this:

```
foo := int64(0)
bar := func(foo int64) {
   // do slow things with param foo (not the local foo var)
}
go bar(foo)
```

In this example the anonymous function will see and use its parameter `foo` and not the local variable `foo`. This may or may not be what you want (depending on whether the handler also uses the `foo` and whether changes made by any of the goroutines need to be visible to the other - but that would require synchronization anyway, which would be superseded by a channel solution).

Answer (score 1):

If you care for acknowledgement for the mail, then the posted code won't help. Running the code in separate goroutine makes it independent and the server reply will be success even if the mail is not sent due to some error in the goroutine function.