# Redirection to a page issue in Go

Tags: go, ibm-cloud

I am serving index.html through go. However, depending upon certain parameters that will be send through the page, go should redirect successfully to a different page. I am getting the below error while trying to execute the code.

**http: multiple response.WriteHeader calls**

```
func main() {
http.HandleFunc("/", func(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {

    http.ServeFile(w, r, r.URL.Path[1:])
    fmt.Println(r.FormValue("login"))

    if r.FormValue("signup") == "signup" {
        signup(w, r)
    } else if r.FormValue("login") == "login" {
        if login(w, r) {
            if r.Method == "POST" {
                fmt.Println("I m here")
                http.Redirect(w, r, "http://localhost:8080/home.html" (http://localhost:8080/home.html') , http.StatusSeeOther)
            }

        }

    }

})
var port string
if port = os.Getenv("PORT"); len(port) == 0 {
    port = DEFAULT_PORT
}
log.Fatal(http.ListenAndServe(":"+port, nil))
}
```

Comment: You cannot ServeFile and afterwards try to redirect. Each HTTP request can be answered exactly once and sending a redirect is an answer.

Comment: Search for your error (in bold above) on stackoverflow and you'll find lots of illustrations of the same problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As already mentioned in the comments and implied in the error message,
you can't change the response header twice:

- When `http.ServeFile(w, r, r.URL.Path[1:])` is called in some point `w.WriteHeader(statusCode)` will be called. In other words, an HTTP response will be sent with `statusCode` as status code.
- `singup` or `http.Redirect` sends an HTTP response after calling `w.WriteHeader`.

So it is very confusing which response should be sent.
You may want to check `signup` and `login` first and if none then call `http.ServeFile`

```
http.HandleFunc("/", func(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
    fmt.Println(r.FormValue("login"))
    switch {
    case r.FormValue("signup") == "signup":
        signup(w, r)
    case r.FormValue("login") == "login" && login(w,r):
        if r.Method == "POST" {
            fmt.Println("I m here")
            http.Redirect(w, r, "http://localhost:8080/home.html" (http://localhost:8080/home.html') , http.StatusSeeOther)
    default:
        http.ServeFile(w, r, r.URL.Path[1:])
    }
})
```

More about [`why WriteHeader is warning you about this`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41582168/1929635) from [a probably duplicated thread](https://stackoverflow.com/q/27972715/1929635)